# POST requests sent without body randomly

Tags: angular, spring-boot, axios, http-post, http-status-code-400

I have an Angular frontend that calls Java Spring Boot backend API. The frontend sends the following request multiple times to the backend but some of them fail with status code **400**. Logged error is `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing`. But when I look at the *Network* tab in Chrome the request looks good and if I send it again it's successful. But the weirdest part is that if I call it via *curl* it never fails.

Frontend:

```js
const endpoint = 'BACKEND_URL/settings';
const data = [{"id":123,"settings":"SETTINGS"}];
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  'Authorization': 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
};
const params = {};

axios.post(endpoint, data, { headers, params })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status, response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error', error.response.status);
  });
```

Backend:

```java
@Api(tags = "API name", description = "API description")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SettingsController {

    @ApiOperation("Endpoint name")
    @PostMapping(path = "/settings", consumes =     MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> updateSettings(@RequestBody @ApiParam("description") List<Settings> settings) throws ApiException {
        // unreachable code when there is no body
    }
}
```

Call with **curl**:

```sh
curl -X POST \
  BACKEND_URL/settings \
  -H 'Authorization: ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '[{"id":123,"settings":"SETTINGS"}]'
```

Comment: can you share the chrome request screenshot for failed and passing one?

Comment: try to remove the consumes  attribute

Comment: out of interest, why are you using axios, instead of the angular http client?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to send data in the body part using string format (not in the array format), can you give it a try using below code -

```
const data = [{"id":123,"settings":"SETTINGS"}];
....

axios.post(endpoint, JSON.stringify(data), { headers, params })
....
```

Comment: The same result. :/